How can I detect when dotnet watch has hot reloaded?
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core application and using dotnet watch for development. When dotnet watch performs a hot reload, the application doesn't restart, and lifecycle events like ApplicationStarted or ApplicationStopped are not triggered.
I would like to detect when a hot reload occurs (e.g., when a file change triggers the reload). Ideally, I want to log or execute some custom logic whenever hot reload happens.
I've tried monitoring lifecycle events like IHostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted, but these don't get triggered during hot reloads. I've also looked into using middleware, but that only captures incoming requests.
How can I reliably detect and respond to hot reload events in an ASP.NET Core application without having to watch for file changes?

I'm wondering if your question is a duplicate of this one asking about Hot Reload events - but dotnet watch does more than just Hot Reload (e.g. dotnet watch can perform other actions instead, like a total process restart).

Keep out with bounties of this magnitude. In the past I immediately got two answers of people who had just entered the question in ChatGPT, hoping for me to fall into their trap :-)

Question - can you elaborate on what TYPE of project this is?, i.e.: Blazor, Console app, MVC, etc.?  Thanks.

This may be of some help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70011986/hot-reload-notification-event

Microsoft's has article on the topic - Extend .NET Hot Reload using MetadataUpdateHandler (C#, Visual Basic). Basically you drop the following code  in your app:
#if DEBUG
[assembly: System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataUpdateHandlerAttribute(typeof(YourAppNamespace.HotReloadService))]

namespace YourAppNamespace;

public static class HotReloadService
{
    public static event Action<Type[]?>? UpdateApplicationEvent;

    internal static void ClearCache(Type[]? types)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hot Reload Service event - ClearCache");
    }

    internal static void UpdateApplication(Type[]? types)
    {
        UpdateApplicationEvent?.Invoke(types);

        Console.WriteLine("Hot Reload Service event - UpdateApplication");
    }
}
#endif

And that's it, those two methods will be called on reload:

Note - updating the file itself triggers the hot reload =)
